# How do I best duck-type this Go DisjointSets data structure?

Tags: go

I have a DisjointSets data structure (pulled from Cormen), implemented in Go to work with `int64`.

```
type DisjointSets struct {
    ranks map[int64]int64
    p map[int64]int64
}

// New returns a new DisjointSets
func NewDisjointSets() *DisjointSets {
    d := DisjointSets{map[int64]int64{}, map[int64]int64{}}
    return &d
}

// MakeSet adds element x to the disjoint sets in its own set
func (d *DisjointSets) MakeSet(x int64) {
    d.p[x] = x
    d.ranks[x] = 0
}

// Link assigns x to y or vice versa, depending on the rank of each
func (d *DisjointSets) Link(x, y int64) {
    if d.ranks[x] > d.ranks[y] {
        d.p[y] = x
    } else {
        d.p[x] = y
        if d.ranks[x] == d.ranks[y] {
            d.ranks[y] += 1
        }
    }
}

// FindSet returns the set in which an element x sits
func (d *DisjointSets) FindSet(x int64) int64 {
    if x != d.p[x] {
        d.p[x] = d.FindSet(d.p[x])
    }
    return d.p[x]
}

// Union combines two elements x and y into one set.
func (d *DisjointSets) Union(x, y int64) {
    d.Link(d.FindSet(x), d.FindSet(y))
}
```

I'd like to write as little incremental code as possible to use this structure for `float64`, `string`, etc. How do I do this?

**What I've tried so far**

I've read everything I can about Interfaces, but I just don't seem to understand how to apply it without having to write a complete implementation for each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was the issue you stumbled upon when using interfaces? You should be able to easily translate that code to use `interface{}` as the element types and have it working with any type that has equality defined for it (can [work as map keys](http://golang.org/ref/spec#KeyType)).

Something along the lines of:

- http://play.golang.org/p/uNcYWltd50

Comment: Ah, I got it. I was turning ranks into map[interface{}]interface{}, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Go does not have templates so I do not think there is an elegant way to do this.  You might try changing the class to take `interface{}` instead of int64.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to implement the classical union-find algorithm.

Why can't you keep what you've got, and just layer on top of this a mapping from whatever thing you want (`float64`, `string`, etc.) to an `int64`?  Then you don't have to change your original code at all.  Think composition.

Concretely, add a map from whatever domain you want, like `string`:

```
var m1 map[string]int64
...
m1["hello"] = 0
m2["world"] = 1
```

and then, whenever you want to figure out what set it belongs to, use `m1` to go from strings to its integer representation for the element, and then your original code to find the parent representative.